# Magento 2 with 300.000 sku became slow

Tags: magento2.4

I am building a magento 2.4.2 in a vps. Problem is that when I imported many sku became really slow. It is running on vps with plesk. I am using porto theme and before adding sku was fast. Now it takes too long to load. I am thinking of transferring it in vps with cpanel and varnish. Will this resolve the problem? I now have 300.000 sku and will go up to 400.000.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on CPanel, you may check how your website is using the resources. Then, you may understand if it is a problem of CPU, RAM, File Storage etc.

Data is in the Metrics Tab as shown below. On the right side, you have a summary report. If the metric is at rick, it goes yellow. If in over, in red.

I would also recommend looking at robots or IPs trying to access your website. The Visitors section shows a summary of it. I usually export to excel and run a procv for counting section of IPs. I very often block a sequence of IPs.

Don't forget to use google speed test to get a feedback on it as well. You may be required to install an extension to compress images and minify content.

Hope that helps.

[image]